# Insert value if recieved value is null

Tags: php, mysql

so, i'm trying to show a certain value in a table row, if the value recieved by post is null. 
So far i've got this as my small database (it's in spanish):

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS fantasmas;
CREATE DATABASE fantasmas;
USE fantasmas;

CREATE TABLE tipos(
ID tinyint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
TIPO VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE datos(
ID tinyint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
ARCHIVO VARCHAR(30),
AVISTAMIENTO VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
LOCALIDAD VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
INFO VARCHAR(200),
FKTIPOS TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED,
FOREIGN KEY (FKTIPOS) REFERENCES tipos(ID) 
);

INSERT INTO tipos (TIPO) VALUES('Vapor'), ('Forma Animal'), ('Forma Humanoide'), ('Dios/Semidios'),('No Catalogado');
```

Those inserted values into "tipos" are then showed in options like this:

```
    <select name="tipos">
     <option value="sintipo">---------</option>
        <?php
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rta)):
            $tipo = $row['TIPO'];
            echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$tipo.'</option>';
            endwhile;
         ?>
</select>
```

After, when the form is sent, the inset to the table, looks like this, it assigns null value if someone select the "------" option:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO datos SET NOMBRE='$nombre', AVISTAMIENTO='$lugar', LOCALIDAD='$localidad', INFO='$info', ARCHIVO='$ruta', FKTIPOS = NULLIF('$tipo','sintipo')";
```

All the data filled in the form, is then showed in a different row of a table.
What I need now, is that, if someone selects the "------" option, the value shown in screen is "No catalogado"
So far I have not been able to do it. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: In the last query $query, you should not wrap $tipo inside single quotes ', like '$tipo', put without it $tipo, and it should work!

Comment: Please sql escape your $params in the query, the code as is shown is prone to SQL injection which is a really big risk

Answer (score 0):

Before the insert happens you can do a null check on the PHP side. Or... you can just use SQL's built in `ISNULL()`

You can also use `CASE` statements in SQL to accomplish this behavior across multiple values.

I know this isn't the most lengthy answer, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your asking for?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO datos SET NOMBRE='$nombre', AVISTAMIENTO='$lugar', LOCALIDAD='$localidad', INFO='$info', ARCHIVO='$ruta', FKTIPOS = " . ($tipo == 'sintipo' ? 'NULL' : "'$tipo'");
```

Be aware that you have very dirty code, you don't even filter and escape income values, as I guess. Try to google `php mysql escape values`.